# Attribute error "command" object has no attribute "role"

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Im making a discord bot to role people with a simple command but I keep running into the same two issues. discord has no attribute role or member, any help is greatly appreciated.

```
from discord.ext import commands
from keep_alive import keep_alive
from discord.utils import get

token = "not gonna show ofc"

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "$")

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("bot is ready")

@client.command()
async def test(ctx, role: discord.Role, user: discord.Member):
    if ctx.author.guild_permissions.administrator:
     await user.add_roles(role)
     await ctx.send(f"given {role.mention} to {user.mention}")

keep_alive()

client.run(token)
```

Comment: Please copy/paste the *exact* error message into your question.

Comment: Remember that Python is case-sensitive, so `role` is not the same as `Role`.

Comment: What is the syntax of the `test` command?

Comment: dont know what you mean could you rephrase @barmar

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Attribute: 'Command' object has no attribute 'role' i have tried with Role and role. its the same error but just capital and no capital r.

Comment: You're implementing the code that responds to a discord command named `test`. So does the `test` command have a `role` parameter?

Comment: i think the fact that i dont know what you mean is giving me the error, what should i add to give it one

Comment: @rocks2260 can you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70945287/edit) your post to include the _full_ traceback?

Answer (score 0):

Is this your full Code?
if yes you should import discord, then your code should work just fine.